# Scan a number of names, print names (number==amount of names) and print Hello to each of them

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and have a task: Scanner a number of "strangers' " names, then read these names and print "Hello+name" to the console. If number of strangers is zero, then print "Looks empty", if the number is negative, then print "Looks negative to me".
So the input and output to console should look like this:

```
3
Den
Ken
Mel
Hello, Den
Hello, Ken
Hello, Mel
```

So I have this code edited from someone with some related task, but it seems I miss something as I am new to Java...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the size of an Array");
int num = input.nextInt();

while (num==0) {
  System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
  break;

} while (num<0) {
  System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
  break;
}

String[] numbers = new String[num];
for (int i=0; i< numbers.length;i++) {
  System.out.println("Hello, " +input.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: You want to print stuff **if**  a number is 0 or negative, not **while** a number is zero or negative. That's the difference between a condition (what you're looking for) and a loop (what you're actually using).

Comment: Also, judging by the output you're expecting you'll need two loops: one to read the data and one to print "Hello name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of an Array");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        if(num==0) {
            System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        }
        else if(num<0) {
            System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
        }
        else {
            String numbers[] = new String[num];
            input.nextLine();
            for (int i=0; i< num;i++) {
              numbers[i]=input.nextLine();
            }
            for (int i=0; i< numbers.length;i++) {
              System.out.println("Hello, " +numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how your code will look and you'll need to add member function input.nextLine(); to read newline character, so there can't be problem regarding input

Answer (score 1):

With using do while loop you can ask the number to the user again and again if it is negative number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    String name;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //The loop asks a number till the number is nonnegative
    do{
        
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of strangers: ");
    num = scan.nextInt();
    
    if(num<0) {
        
        System.out.println("It cannot be a negative number try again.");
    }else if(num==0) {
        
        System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        break;
    }else{
        
        String[] strangers = new String[num];
        //Takes the names and puts them to the strangers array
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
            System.out.print("Name " + (i+1) + " : ");
            name = scan.next();
            strangers[i] = name;
        }
        
        //Printing the array
        for(int j=0; j<num; j++) {
            System.out.println("Hello, " + strangers[j]);
        }
        break;
        
    }
    }while(num<0);

}
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't clearly address the requirements.  The question clearly states, "if the number is negative, then print "Looks negative to me"".  This means that a negative number is valid and warrants a valid response.  Other things of note: arrays are declared on the variable declaration, not the variable name.  `String strangers[] = new String[num]` should be rewritten as `String[] strangers = new String[num]`.  Additionally, it's usually helpful to provide explanations of your answers and possible supporting information.  You can find more information on how to write good answers in the